# Accessing Android Menu Items

Tags: android

Within the **onOptionsItemSelected()** method of Android for **menus**, I am calling a method named getQueries() which will determine what checkboxes are checked and then return a string based on that. However, I am getting a null reference value whenever I try and access an item from the menu. Any ideas? My getQueries method is below and I can provide more code if need. I think I may be initializing menu wrong, but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

```
public String getQueries() {

    String q = "";
    Menu menu = (Menu)findViewById(R.menu.main_activity_actions);
    if (menu.findItem(R.id.action_bread).isChecked()) {
        q = "bread";
    }
    if (menu.findItem(R.id.action_cheese).isChecked()) {
        q = "cheese";
    }
    Log.d("query", q);
    return q;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your code work:

```
public String getQueries(MenuItem itm)
{
    String q = "";

    switch (itm.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.action_bread:
        {
            q = "bread";
            break;
        }
        case R.id.action_bread:
        {
            q = "cheese";
            break;
        }
    }

    Log.d("query", q);
    return q;
}
```

Call it from onMnuItemSelected passing the MenuItem as a parameter.

But I'd prefer to do it so:
(Having declared q as a local variable)

```
@Override
public final boolean onMenuItemSelected
(final int featureId, final MenuItem itm)
{
    String q = "";

    switch (itm.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.action_bread:
        {
            q = "bread";
            break;
        }
        case R.id.action_bread:
        {
            q = "cheese";
            break;
        }
    }
    Log.d("query", q);

    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, itm);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Klauss. What I am trying to do those is check the values of all the checkboxes in the menu to form a string full of multiple queries based off what check boxes are checked. Any ideas on that? I somehow need to iterate through the menu items, check if they are checked, and then append the string if they are checked.

Comment: You can do that DIFFERENTLY and much MORE EASILY: Valorize some boolean variables each corresponding to a MenuItem checked or not and then - when you click on a button (for instance), you prepare your query basing on those values. DONE!

Comment: Looks like I'm gonna take this approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can store a reference to your `Menu` in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and use it later. `findViewById(R.menu.whatever)` returns `null`.

Comment: Correct, the null reference is where the issue is occurring. So I would need to create global variables and assign them in the onCreateOptionMenu() and then I can reference them later in the code?